# Laravel eloquent dynamic slug possible?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I'm working on Laravel 5.3 and I have a query like :

```
        $types = DB::table('offers')
        ->select('type')
        ->get();
```

So, with this query, I can get all `type` in my tables `offers`.

The column `type` is a `String`, and is this possible to add a dynamic field in this query to get the slug version on `type` ?

Laravel has a function `str_slug`, can we use it ? Or a SQL function ?

Thanks !